# Programa em Javascript para calcular a fórmula de bhaskara não funciona

Tags: javascript

estou desenvolvendo um programa simples para ajudar no cálculo da fórmula de bhaskara (aquela que aprendemos na escola) já possuo um código feito em C que funciona perfeitamente, porém quando fui "portar" para JavaScript, ele simplesmente não funciona, testei algumas funções separadamente ( a função if e a Math.sqrt() funcionam perfeitamente isoladas) porém não consigo fazer com que funcione.

Estarei disponibilizando o código em JavaScript (que não funciona) e o código em C (que funciona), agradeço de antemão aqueles que me ajudarem.

Código em JavaScript (não funciona)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title> Cálculo de Bhaskara </title>

    <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

// Abaixo recebemos do usuário o valor do A, B e C.

    var valora = parseInt(prompt("Digite o valor de A: "));
    var valorb = parseInt(prompt("Digite o valor de B: "));
    var valorc = parseInt(prompt("Digite o valor de C: "));

//  Abaixo calculamos a fórmula propriamente dita.

    var quadradodeb = valorb * valorb;

    var delta = quadradodeb - 4 * (valora * valorc);

//  Abaixo verificamos se o Delta é = 0 ou <0 e se é possível continuar a calcular.

    if(delta < 0){
        document.write("Não é possível calcular pois o Delta é menor que zero.");
    }

    if(delta == 0){
        document.write("O Delta é zero, portando os valores de X1 e X2 serão iguais.<br>");
    }


    var valordebneg = valordeb * (-1);  /* INVERTE O SINAL DO B */

    var raizdedelta = Math.sqrt(delta); /* CALCULA A RAIZ DO DELTA, NO CASO, FEITO PELA FUNÇÃO Math.sqrt(variável) */

    var divisor = 2 * valordea; /* CALCULA O DIVISOR, NO CASO QUE DIVIDIRÁ B + RAIZ DE DELTA */

    var resultadox1 = (valordebneg + raizdedelta) / divisor;    /* CALCULA O X1 */

    var resultadox2 = (valordebneg - raizdedelta) / divisor;    /* CALCULA O X2 */


    document.write("∆ = B² - 4 X A X C<br>");
    document.write("∆ = " + quadradodeb + " - 4 X " + valora + " X " + valorb);
    document.write("<br>∆ = " + delta);

    document.write("<br>X = -B +ou- √∆ <br>__________________<br>      2 X A");
    document.write("<br> X = " + valordebneg + " +ou- " + raizdedelta + "<br>____________________<br>      2 X " + valora);
    document.write("<br><br>X1 = " + quadradodeb + " + " + raizdedelta + " / " + divisor);
    document.write("<br>X1 = " +resultadox1);

    document.write("<br><br>X2 = " + quadradodeb + " - " + raizdedelta + " / " + divisor);
    document.write("<br>X2 = " +resultadox2);

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Código em C (funciona)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>   /* função sqrt(); */
int main()
{

    float valordea, valordeb, valordec, resultadox1, resultadox2, quadradodeb, delta, valordex, raizdedelta, valordebneg, divisor;


/* AQUI SE INPUTAM OS VALORES DE A B e C. */

    printf("Este programa faz e demonstra o processo da formula de Bhaskara.\n Siga o exemplo para inserir os Valores:\n (A)*X2 (B)*X (C) = 0\n\n");

    printf("Digite o valor de A:\n");
    scanf("%f",&valordea);

    printf("\nDigite o valor de B:\n");
    scanf("%f",&valordeb);

    printf("\nDigite o valor de C:\n");
    scanf("%f",&valordec);

/* AQUI SE APLICA A FÓRMULA DE BHASKARA EM VARIÁVEIS QUE SERÃO MOSTRADAS DEPOIS */

    quadradodeb=valordeb*valordeb;  /* CALCULA O QUADRADO DE B */

    delta=quadradodeb-4*valordea*valordec;  /* CALCULA O DELTA */

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    /* CALCULA SE É POSSÍVEL PROSSEGUIR COM A CONTA */

    if(delta<0) /* ESCREVE NA TELA CASO O DELTA SEJA MENOR QUE ZERO. */
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\n Nao e possivel calcular, o delta e menor que zero. \n\n");
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    if(delta==0)    /* ESCREVA NA TELA SE O X1 E X2 SERÃO IGUAIS */
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\nO valor de delta e zero, portanto as duas raizes (X1 e X2) sao iguais.\n\n");
    }

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    valordebneg=valordeb*(-1);  /* INVERTE O SINAL DO B */

    raizdedelta=sqrt(delta);    /* CALCULA A RAIZ DO DELTA */

    divisor=2*valordea; /* CALCULA O DIVISOR, NO CASO QUE DIVIDIRÁ B + RAIZ DE DELTA */

    resultadox1=(valordebneg+raizdedelta)/divisor;  /* CALCULA O X1 */

    resultadox2=(valordebneg-raizdedelta)/divisor;  /* CALCULA O X2 */

system("cls");

    printf("Delta=B2-4*A*C \n");    /* MOSTRA A FÓRMULA */
    printf("\nDelta = %.2f - 4 * %.2f * %.2f\n",quadradodeb, valordea, valordeb);   /*MOSTRA O RESULTANDO NA FÓRMULA */
    printf("\nDelta = %.2f\n\n\n",delta);

    printf("X = -B +ou- Raiz de Delta \n _________________________\n           2*A         \n\n");  /* MOSTRA A FÓRMULA */

    printf("\nX1 = %.2f + %.2f Dividido por %.2f\n", quadradodeb, raizdedelta, divisor);    /*MOSTRA O RESULTANDO NA FÓRMULA */
    printf("\nX1 = %.2f\n\n\n",resultadox1);

    printf("\nX2 = %.2f - %.2f Dividido por %.2f\n", quadradodeb, raizdedelta, divisor);/*MOSTRA O RESULTANDO NA FÓRMULA */
    printf("\nX2 = %.2f\n\n\n",resultadox2);

    system ("pause");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia Luis,

Dei uma refatorada no seu código e agora está funcionando.

O seu problema estava no nome das variáveis que você deve ter cometido algum deslize na hora de digitar:

Onde: `var valordebneg = valordeb * (-1);` **valordeb** não existe. Você tinha declarado: `valorb`.

Além do mais, é muito importante você aguardar os elementos da página serem completamente interpretados pelo navegador para poder manipula-los utilizando o JavaScript, para isso, utilize a função `window.onload` que irá executar uma função assim que um evento for disparado pelo navegador indicando que os elementos estão OK!

Enfim, abaixo está o código funcionando. 
Efetuei os testes com os números: *a = 1, b = 3 e c = –10*.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var valora = parseInt(prompt("Digite o valor de A: "));
      var valorb = parseInt(prompt("Digite o valor de B: "));
      var valorc = parseInt(prompt("Digite o valor de C: "));

      var quadradodeb = valorb * valorb;

      console.log(quadradodeb);

      var delta = quadradodeb - 4 * valora * valorc;

      console.log(delta);

      if (delta < 0) {
        document.write("Não é possível calcular pois o Delta é menor que zero.");
        return;
      }

      if (delta == 0) {
        document.write("O Delta é zero, portando os valores de X1 e X2 serão iguais.<br>");
        return;
      }

      var valordebneg = valorb * (-1); /* INVERTE O SINAL DO B */

      var raizdedelta = Math.sqrt(delta); /* CALCULA A RAIZ DO DELTA, NO CASO, FEITO PELA FUNÇÃO Math.sqrt(variável) */

      var divisor = 2 * valora; /* CALCULA O DIVISOR, NO CASO QUE DIVIDIRÁ B + RAIZ DE DELTA */

      var resultadox1 = (valordebneg + raizdedelta) / divisor; /* CALCULA O X1 */

      var resultadox2 = (valordebneg - raizdedelta) / divisor; /* CALCULA O X2 */


      document.write("∆ = B² - 4 X A X C<br>");
      document.write("∆ = " + quadradodeb + " - 4 X " + valora + " X " + valorb);
      document.write("<br>∆ = " + delta);

      document.write("<br>X = -B +ou- √∆ <br>__________________<br>      2 X A");
      document.write("<br> X = " + valordebneg + " +ou- " + raizdedelta + "<br>____________________<br>      2 X " + valora);
      document.write("<br><br>X1 = " + quadradodeb + " + " + raizdedelta + " / " + divisor);
      document.write("<br>X1 = " + resultadox1);

      document.write("<br><br>X2 = " + quadradodeb + " - " + raizdedelta + " / " + divisor);
      document.write("<br>X2 = " + resultadox2);
    }
  </script>
</head>

</html>
```

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Muito Obrigado! fiquei muito tempo procurando problemas mas era algo tão simples, agradeço sua resposta! Em breve este código será parte de um projeto educacional, lembrarei da sua ajuda até o final da conclusão.